# Bootstrap Center align a div horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried simple login page for a sample. But am unable to align the fields to center.  `h:commandButton` is aligned to center. but rest of the fields are does't have any change while keep `<div align="center">`

How do i keep them center aligned?

```
<div align="center">            
    <h:message for="btnSubmit"/>
    <div class='form-row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 form-group required'>
         <label class='control-label'> User Name </label>
          <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" size="12" maxlength="20" 
                       id="userName" value="#{loginController.userName}" 
                       required="true"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
        <div class='col-xs-2 form-group card required'>
           <label class='control-label'>Password</label>
           <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" size="12" maxlength="20"
                        id="password" value="#{loginController.password}"
                        required="true" />
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-row'>
        div class='col-md-12 form-group'>
      <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-success" 
               value="#{bundle['label.Login']}" id="btnSubmit" 
               action="#{loginController.clientLoginAction}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) you'll likely get a even faster response!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simplest way is to add a custom class `.col-center` from your side to it

```
.col-center{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**why this way??** because BS has the methodology of `offset` but it has a drawback as it only works for even column sizes, so only `.col-X-2`, `.col-X-4`, `col-X-6`, `col-X-8` and `col-X-10` are supported.

**Must do :** just make sure that whichever div you want to center, has a div `width` mentioned to it....`.col-center` will do rest of job

Answer (score 6):

As of 2019 Oct,  class="center-block" is dropped and "mx-auto" is introduced for the same purpose in current bootstrap version.

```
<div class="mx-auto bg-warning" style="width:150px">Centered</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

To center a block level element horizontally in bootstrap use Use `center-block` class.

For example:

```
<div class="center-block">...</div>
```

Comment: It is a new class in bootstrap 3.0.1. Make sure you have latest.

Comment: doesn't work form me `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 center-block">`

Comment: Do you have bootstrap 3.0.1 or greater?

Comment: yes using 3.3.6, thouhgh `col-*-offset-*` works perfectly, hence used that